# Thread was being aborted when response.GetResponseStream()

Tags: c#, asynchronous

i m new to async call please help me for update my code with async mehtod which is best way for that 
please suggest

Below is my code

```
        private string GetTranslatedContent(RequestModel oRequestModel, string contentToTranslate)
    {
        string translatedContent = null;
        string uri ="http://sample.com/test/getTranslatedcontent/";
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentToTranslate))
            {
                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri+contentToTranslate);  
                var response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    //here i got translatedContent and  return to caller method
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return translatedContent;
      }
```

this method called from below method and returned translatedContent updated into Database for that specific record id

```
public void TranslateALLDATA()
            {
            ItemsCollection = getDATAFromDBToTranslate();
            foreach (item item in ItemsCollection)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.text))
                {
                    translatedcontnet = GetTranslatedContent(oRequestModel, item.text);
                    //after that update record in table for that item
                    update table text=translatedcontnet where id= item.id;
                }
            }
            }
```

Comment: Isn't the using just nullifying your response stream?

Comment: code in using is var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(string));
                        if (stream != null) translatedContent = (string)dcs.ReadObject(stream); it gives me response string